Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow' to 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView'
I need help, I was doing a small project on windows forms, but I'm getting an error in the StudentDataGridView.SelectRows[0] part of the DataGridView?
my solution did not work therefore who know this solve please help me

Is a bedroom door a house? Or does a house contain a bedroom door?

what do you want to achieve? are you going to get the index of the selected row?
